# Is there a term to refer to a cube-break-down process?

Tags: terminology

The image shown below illustrate the process to break a cube down into 4 small equal cubes.

Is there a term to refer to this process, something like cube-break-down?

[image]

Why would I like to know the term?

Because I am trying to perform this process by coding, and I am wondering if there existing code base to do this.

Comment: Space partitioning would be one way to describe it, your example is similar to an oct-tree partition.

Comment: How about Exploded view?

Answer (score 1):

What about Division or subdivision?